# enabled pseudo class matches links on page?

Tags: css, css-selectors

:enabled psuedo class matches links on page? Is that correct behavior ?

**JSBIN**

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/deruxa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3):

In HTML, `:enabled` is not supposed to match hyperlinks (that is, `a:link, a:visited`), since hyperlinks don't have a disabled state by virtue of not being [form elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled). Hyperlinks are not mentioned in [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#disabled-elements) of the spec either, which lists what types of elements can have a disabled state.

If the `:enabled` pseudo is matching hyperlinks on whatever browser you're using, then that browser is not behaving correctly. It doesn't match them on Firefox, or IE.

Answer (score 2):

No cant be on anchor tag , it is mosly related to input tags and elements

The :enabled CSS pseudo-class represents any enabled element. An element is enabled if it can be activated (e.g. selected, clicked on or accept text input) or accept focus. The element also has an disabled state, in which it can't be activated or accept focus.

links or anchor tags can onle have following psuedo classes

- a:link
- a:visited
- a:hover
- a:focus
- a:active

Comment: Yes I know, but I think that enabled pseudo class should work only on elements that accepts disabled attribute. 
There are more elements that can be clicked or focused and are not affected by :enabled selector. Look here https://html5.org/r/8818